# using SqlSensor in Airflow, create a query that checks if all days from previous month are in a table

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would this be a correct/fast way to check if all days from the previous month are in my table? My Snowflake table has a 'date' column that is a 'date' type:

I'm doing this but I feel there must be a better way?

```
SELECT *
FROM dfp.revenue_allocation
WHERE YEAR("date") = '{{ execution_date.year }}'
AND MONTH("date") = '{{ execution_date.month }}'-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get best performance, expression on columns should be avoided:

```
SELECT *
FROM dfp.revenue_allocation
WHERE "date" >= TRUNC( CAST(? AS DATE) - INTERVAL '1 MONTH', 'MONTH')
  AND "date" < TRUNC( CAST(? AS DATE), 'MONTH');
```

[TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trunc2.html)

> Truncates a date, time, or timestamp to the specified part

Comment: Hello! I've tried this to test out in our table:
SELECT *
FROM dfp.revenue_allocation
WHERE "date" >= TRUNC('2021-07-13' - INTERVAL '1 MONTH', 'MONTH')
  AND "date" < TRUNC( '2021-07-13', 'MONTH');
but I see the error: 
 Invalid argument types for function '-': (VARCHAR(10), INTERVAL)

Comment: @KristiLuna The provided parameter should be explicitly casted to DATE either by using: `CAST('2021-07-13' AS DATE)` or `'2021-07-13'::DATE`